# Emacs Hexl to read device files?

Tags: emacs

I have to manually edit a FAT 16 partition. After trying few hex editors, I decided to try Emacs Hexl.

```
sudo emacs -> M-x hexl-find-file -> /dev/sdb
```

The commands open device file but its empty, although others hex editors (including 'sudo cat /dev/sdb') show its content.

Why so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, There is no way to read/write device file in Emacs.

See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispLimitations

Comment: Any hex editor can, so it looks like to be the Emacs's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to open the entire drive at once would be far too big.  Use `dd` to transfer parts of the disk to/from a file and edit the file in hexl mode.